# Unable to load DLL 'VSPerf110.dll'

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012

When I publish my web application and have `Precompile during publishing` checked I get this error on my webserver:

> Unable to load DLL 'VSPerf110.dll': The specified module could not be
>   found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)

The application works if I don't Precompile. How can I fix this?

Here's my settings for publishing:

[image: Publish with precompile]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK it sounds like this application is trying to make use of the Profiler API on the production server. There may be some **performance tracking Profile code** in this application that may need to be **commented out or removed**.

Per this MSDN documentation on the Profileer API for VS 2012, "Your build must reference the Microsoft.VisualStudio.Profiler.dll library, located in the Microsoft Visual Studio 9\Team Tools\Performance Tools directory."

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb514149(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Ive tried to make a reference to the Microsoft.VisualStudio.Profiler.dll but without any success. 
Long time ago I ran the Code Analysis in VS2012 and it added a file about supressed messages. Removed that too, but without any success. How can I find left over Profile code in my code?

Comment: Try doing a global find **(Ctrl + Shift + F)** in your Solution for: **Microsoft.VisualStudio.Profiler**. That should reveal any and all code files that are using the Profiler namespace.

Comment: Nothing was found in the code. Is it possible that Visual Studio adds it during precompile?

Comment: I just decompile the global.asax dll and VS adds Profiling code to it. I guess its a setting somewhere I have to untick.

Comment: I found it! In the web.config refences to Microsoft.VisualStudio.Enterprise.Common.AspPerformanceInstrumenter and Microsoft.VisualStudio.Enterprise.AspNetHelper had been added. Removing those references fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error message in Visual Studio 2015 and wanted to post a different solution in case it helps someone else. In my case, I had used Visual Studio's Performance Profiler to do some performance analysis. However, I never modified my code to add references to Microsoft.VisualStudio.Profiler.dll. When I copied my files to our test server, I received the error message.

I searched my code for "VSPerf110" but found nothing. Finally I tried using a separate search utility to search all files in the directory and found it: the string "VSPerf110.dll" was found in one of the compiled dlls, despite the fact that none of my code had changed.

To fix the issue, I deleted all my performance analysis output files (these are non-code files generated by Visual Studio), and did a Clean/Rebuild on the solution. After this, searching for the string "VSPerf110.dll" returned 0 results. When I copied the recompiled dlls to the test server, the error message went away.