# Missing File Publish Options

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I was going to Publish my website today, but Im missing a few options so I can disable Precompile (as it breaks my website, [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22906140/unable-to-load-dll-vsperf110-dll)). I'm glad I took a screenshot of the publish settings 2 weeks ago or I would think I have gone crazy!

Is this caused by a new update in VS2012 (I noticed that a new upgrade was availble, but I didn't do anything) or have I screwed up a setting somewhere?

Now Im missing the file publish options:
[image: Missing file options]

This screen was taken 2 weeks ago:
[image: File publish options]

Comment: I'm having this same issue now, and I don't know what has changed...I can't even find the Web Publish Activity window that is in the answer below...

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround to disable the Precompile:

Open the Properties folder in the project and then the PublishProfiles folder. Find the publish profile, open it and set `PrecompileBeforePublish` to `False`

Answer (score 0):

The last used web publish profile must be **MSDeploy**.

You can set the publish profile in the **Web Publish Activity** window. 
To show it go to **View -> Other Windows -> Web Publish Activity**.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

And now you'll see your missing configuration

[image]